# Black hole and white hole question

Tags: black-holes, white-holes

If white holes are the other ends of black holes, what if a black hole absorbs the white hole it is connected to, and then if it is absorbed by another blackhole bigger than the first, but the white hole smaller and absorbed that white hole then the 2nd black hole was to just stop existing, would its white hole shoot out any matter would the 1st black hole absorb it the 1st white hole shoot it out the matter and the blackhole absorbs it again, and it loops indefinitly, would the black hole grow indefinitly.

I know I could have simplifed the question, and it would probably be the same answer, honsetly I made it complicated for no reason really, but as a 13 year old I feel I still am asking a really good question.

Really what im asking is if a blackhole absorbs the white hole connected to it, then absorbs any matter would it just grow infinitly?

Answer (score 1):

> Really what im asking is if a blackhole absorbs the white hole connected to it, then absorbs any matter would it just grow infinitly?

[White holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole) (unlike black holes) are entirely hypothetical and really are not expected to exist.  They're basically an abstract mathematical extension of the mathematics of a black hole.  While there is some serious work done on them, I think it would be fair to describe them as an interesting abstraction rather than something we expect to find.

With that in mind the idea that a while hole could be absorbed by it's corresponding black hole would be very odd.  I don't know of any study on this (although I'm certainly not an expert in this).

In general the universe seems to keep very strict mathematical balances on things like energy.  There does not seem to be a way to create some kind of infinitely growing loop like you are describing.  If we found a theory saying something like that most physicists would expect it to be wrong because it breaks the basic rule of conservation of energy.

Answer (score 1):

White holes are not what you think they are.

First, white holes are not part of a realistic spacetime. They show up when there is perfect spherical symmetry, no angular momentum, and no matter or energy. This is in contrast to black holes which seem to be a very robust finding and occur even with realistic matter distributions, substantial asymmetry, angular momentum, etc.

Second, in the mathematical idealization where they do occur, they are more like a moment in time than a place. In an ideal Schwarzschild spacetime the white hole is a singularity in the past and the black hole is a singularity in the future. Tomorrow cannot “absorb” yesterday.

Third, if we assume that a white hole would still exist with a small amount of matter shooting out of it, then because the white hole is in the past that matter would have already shot out of it. There is no way that we can get new matter shooting out of a white hole.

Finally, you mention white holes as “the other end” of a black hole. It sounds like you think that they are spatially connected so that matter which enters a black hole here comes out of a white hole there. But they are other ends of time. The white hole is in the past and the black hole is in the future, and they are connected the other way. Matter which leaves the white hole can enter the black hole, but never the reverse.